# Pycharm stops working on mobaxterm and wsl2

Tags: pycharm, wsl-2, mobaxterm

I am using WSL2 and MobaXterm to run Pycharm Community with graphics. It works great when I open MobaXterm the first time and start Pycharm. If I leave the computer for a while and come back, Pycharm has disappeared. If I restart Pycharm it is incredibly slow and the only thing that works is to restart the computer.

Has anyone experienced this and know a solution?

Here is the output:

```
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
2021-01-18 22:22:34,772 [   1252]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Resource bundle redefinition for plugin 'com.jetbrains.pycharm.community.customization'. Old value: messages.ActionsBundle, new value: messages.PyBundle
2021-01-18 22:22:35,298 [   1778]   WARN - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Attempt to load key 'actionSystem.getContextByRecentMouseEvent' for not yet loaded registry
2021-01-18 22:22:36,601 [   3081]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2021-01-18 22:22:36,606 [   3086]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2021-01-18 22:22:36,607 [   3087]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 6.5" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2021-01-18 22:22:36,607 [   3087]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Visual Studio" not found [Plugin: com.intellij]
2021-01-18 22:22:37,461 [   3941]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.github]
2021-01-18 22:22:37,492 [   3972]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Eclipse" not found [Plugin: PythonCore]
2021-01-18 22:22:37,492 [   3972]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "NetBeans 6.5" not found [Plugin: PythonCore]
2021-01-18 22:22:43,224 [   9704]   WARN - x.cache.CachedStatusCalculator - Hash mismatch between count and status: RevListCount[value=<null>,status=NO_REMOTE,top=<null>] ahead, RevListCount[value=<null>,status=NO_REMOTE,top=<null>] behind, status=NO_REMOTE <> RepoStatus[localHash=ece7a288c8405aa953f9a50f5a97e92d805c5005,localBranch=refs/heads/create_neural_network_toy,remote=RepoStatusRemote[remoteTrackingBranch=<null>,parentBranch=<null>,parentHash=<null>]]
2021-01-18 22:22:43,392 [   9872]   WARN - a.repo.GitUntrackedFilesHolder - Ignoring untracked file under another root: /home/name/Code/privateprojects/workspace-python/club_detections_1.0/src/__pycache__/data_loader.cpython-38.pyc; root: file:///home/name/Code/privateprojects; mapped root: null
2021-01-18 22:22:53,888 [  20368]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - Some skeletons failed to generate
2021-01-18 22:22:53,888 [  20368]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - PyQt5.QtWebEngine
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - caffe2.python.caffe2_pybind11_state
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libc10
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libcaffe2_detectron_ops
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libcaffe2_module_test_dynamic
2021-01-18 22:22:53,889 [  20369]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libcaffe2_observers
2021-01-18 22:22:53,890 [  20370]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libshm
2021-01-18 22:22:53,890 [  20370]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libtorch
2021-01-18 22:22:53,890 [  20370]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libtorch_cpu
2021-01-18 22:22:53,890 [  20370]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libtorch_global_deps
2021-01-18 22:22:53,891 [  20371]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torch.lib.libtorch_python
2021-01-18 22:22:53,891 [  20371]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torchvision._C
2021-01-18 22:22:53,891 [  20371]   WARN - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - torchvision.image
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.cache` seems to do the trick.